# Enable CORS Request for hostname using IP address

Tags: functions

I had my site homepage using ip address (only homepage) as host name and the other part still use usual hostname.

There are error in homepage because CORS Policy.

I try to add_filter in functions.php file but still don't work. This is the code inside.

```
add_filter( 'allowed_http_origin', 'add_allowed_origin' );
function add_allowed_origin( $origin ) {
     $origin[] = 'http://111.111.111.111';
     return $origin;
}
```

Error Message

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at http://example.com from origin 'http://111.111.111.111' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: There is huge difference between `allowed_http_origins` (plural) and `allowed_http_origin` (singular).

Comment: I had change the Code. But error message still same. Anything else can i do @MaxYudin ?